Changing a button state depending on a text field in ttkbootstrap/tkinter between classes
I'm trying to learn some basic ttkbootstrap/tkinter in Python, and I've got a small scenario I can't seem to understand and work around.
I have the following "Demo" code below, which is loosely pieced together with some samples I found online.
import ttkbootstrap as tb

from tkinter import *
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

class MyApp(tb.Frame):

    global appname, appver
    appname = "Test App"
    appver = "0.1B"

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=20, pady=20)

        # Variables
        self.TextBox1_var = tb.StringVar(value='')

        # Label Frame builder
        option_text = "Test"
        self.option_lf = tb.Labelframe(self, text=option_text, padding=5)
        self.option_lf.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, anchor=N)

        # Build the form
        self.TextBox1_Row()
        self.Button1_Row()

    def TextBox1_Row(self):
        """Add row to labelframe"""
        TextBox1_row = tb.Frame(self.option_lf)
        TextBox1_row.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)
        TextBox1_lbl = tb.Label(TextBox1_row, text="Input:", width=12)
        TextBox1_lbl.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(15, 0))
        TextBox1_ent = tb.Entry(TextBox1_row, textvariable=self.TextBox1_var)
        TextBox1_ent.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=YES, padx=5)
        self.TextBox1_var.trace_add("write", lambda name, index, mode, sv=self.TextBox1_var: MonitorTextChanges.TextBox1_callback(self.TextBox1_var))

    def Button1_Row(self):
        """Add row to labelframe"""
        Button1_Row = tb.Frame(self.option_lf)
        Button1_Row.pack(fill=X, expand=YES, pady=5)
        Button1_Go = tb.Button(
            master=Button1_Row, 
            text="Go", 
            width=15,
            state=DISABLED
        )
        Button1_Go.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

class MonitorTextChanges():
    def TextBox1_callback(TextBox1_var):

        if len(TextBox1_var.get()) != 0:
            print(TextBox1_var.get())
            #MyApp.Button1_Row.Button1_Go.config(state="normal")
        else:
            print("Please enter some text!")
            #MyApp.Button1_Row.Button1_Go.config(state="disabled")

def main():
    app = tb.Window(
        title=appname + " - " + appver,
        themename="superhero",
        minsize=(300,150),
        resizable=(True, True),
        scaling=2
    )
    MyApp(app)
    MonitorTextChanges()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I'm attempting to update the state of the button whenever there is present text, and to disable it whenever the text field is empty from between classes, but I cannot seem to figure out how to target the button in the MyApp class.
I've tried the fllowing:
MyApp.Button1_Go.config(state="normal")
which yields
AttributeError: type object 'MyApp' has no attribute 'Button1_Go'. Did you mean: 'Button1_Row'?
MyApp.Button1_Row.config(state="normal")
which yields
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'config'
MyApp.Button1_Row.Button1_Go.config(state="normal")
which yields
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Button1_Go'
So, I'm not sure how to actually target this button in the MyApp class to change the state of it.

[Edit 1]
I've been exploring this further, and I've reached the following point.
I read about passing the classes between each other as an object, tied to a variable, so I've changed the MonitorTextChanges class to have the following:
class MonitorTextChanges():
    def TextBox1_callback(TextBox1_var):
        TargetClass = MyApp()

        if len(TextBox1_var.get()) != 0:
            print(TextBox1_var.get())
            TargetClass.Button1_Go.config(state="normal")
        else:
            print("Please enter some text!")
            TargetClass.Button1_Go.config(state="disabled")

The issue is I'm not passing the argument master and in turn I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: MyApp.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
I understand that this error means I'm not passing the master argument, but I'm not sure if:
A.) I can bypass passing this value.
B.) What specifically I'd need to pass.
From what I gather, the master is referring to the tb.frame, which I believe is the parent class of MyApp. It currently works by passing this as the argument:
    app = tb.Window(
        title=appname + " - " + appver,
        themename="superhero",
        minsize=(300,150),
        resizable=(True, True),
        scaling=2
    )
    MyApp(app)

Which generates the form, but I don't want to generate a form, I simply want to change the state of a button on the existing form. So, I'm confused further of how to pass this state change from one class to another.
Is there a method within ttkbootstrap or tkinter which I can pass, to not "generate a form", but rather to just refresh the existing form?

I don't find your comment helpful. Granted, I probably need to learn some more, but people learn in different ways. Some learn by studying online tutorials, taking classes, and reading books, while some of us learn by simply jumping in, and figuring things out how things work as we go. I think it's pretty judgmental of you to simply suggest I "hit the books". Not everyone's brain functions the same way, and having a platform like Stack Overflow is generally a great resource for someone such as myself to learn and get a better understanding of specific issues I'm facing.

If you have a specific point, topic, link, article, etc. which you could direct me too, which relates to my specific issue, I'd be more than happy to take a look, and try to absorb some information to help me further, but otherwise I will keep digging on my own, trying things, and doing whatever research I can do to try and figure this out on my own.
